# What should I use instead of DS.FixtureAdapter

Tags: ember.js

You gotta love ember.js team... I'm getting this depreciation message saying that: "DS.FixtureAdapter has been deprecated and moved into an unsupported addon: https://github.com/emberjs/ember-data-fixture-adapter/tree/master". Guys maintaining that addon advise that we should use a library similar to `Pretender`. Has anybody done that? Is there a tutorial showing how to integrate this lib so that everything would work as before?

Comment: Although deprecated, the adapter pattern for ember-data is not. If a community maintainer wishes to take over, they are welcome to if not encouraged to.

A quick example for testing with pretender would be as follows: https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-jobs/blob/master/tests/acceptance/posting-test.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `ember-cli` it comes with an `http-mock` out of the box letting you quickly setup fixtures in a more realistic test scenario.  For instance, for a `Conversation` model you would mock it by running the following prompt on your command line.

`ember g http-mock conversations`

This will scaffold an endpoint located at `server/mocks/conversations.js` that your real adapters will use to get data when you run `ember serve`.  You can modify this file to your liking to return whatever fixtures / mock data you want for the various CRUD operations you need.

Answer (score 2):

Server mocks:

- [Ember CLI's `http-mock`](http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#mocks-and-fixtures)

Clientside mocks:

- [Pretender.js](https://github.com/trek/pretender)
- [jQuery mockjax](https://github.com/jakerella/jquery-mockjax)
- [Ember CLI Mirage](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/), basically sugar around Pretender

Clientside mocking has some advantages like portability, making it easy to use in a CI environment, but server mocks let you take advantage of express middleware.

Note: I maintain Mirage. You can watch a screencast & overview [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKG0uh8ZVEY).

Answer (score 1):

I like to use http-mocks with ember-cli. In addition I like to use raw JSON files as the payloads for each endpoint here is an example setup https://github.com/pixelhandler/ember-fixturific/pull/1/files